# Merge three github branches locally

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge, git-bash

Currently I have a scenario where I want to locally merge two branches to a third branch. So the scenario is. FYI I am a noob in github.

1. Master --> Epic_1
2. Master --> Epic_2

Now I want to merge Epic_1 branch first to Master and then merge Epic_2 branch to master on top of merged Epic_1 and Master. I am not sure what to search for to get proper answer so adding this question.
IMPORTANT - I want all of this to be done locally only and nothing should go to remote branch.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout master   # go to master since that’s your target branch
git merge Epic_1      # merge in the first branch
git merge Epic_2      # merge in the second branch
```

This will give you a result that looks approximately like this:

```
            (old) master      master (after merges)
                    ↓           ↓
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- M1 -- M2
                       /      /
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -      /
                    ↑       /
                  Epic_1   /
                          /
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *
                         ↑
                       Epic_2
```

As with everything in Git, this happens only locally, so nothing on any of your remotes is affected. Of course, you can then push the master branch to update it on your remote.

Comment: what command gave you such a beautiful graphical view? Eager to know

Comment: I actually did that by hand… xD

Comment: cool! How long are you using Git ? I understood it from your drawing indeed. :)

Comment: Multiple years already; don’t exactly when I started using it. But I spent quite some time to learn about its internals (I gave a talk about it at uni), so that’s probably “at fault” too ;) But I’m glad you understood it from the drawing—that’s what I was trying to do :)

Comment: @poke, Thanks for the details. I did the same thing. Another thing I wanted to know is can I save this branch as a new branch name in my local machine? So that I can continue checking out other branches and still locally I will have this branch on my machine whenever I need. Thanks again

Comment: @KaushikRay Since you started on `master`, merging those branches in actually updated your master branch, so you already have a branch that reflects those changes. Just like committing something, merging (which commits a merge commit) also progresses the branch pointer. But of course, you can always create a new branch using `git branch newname`; so you could run that before the merges to create a backup branch for the original state.

Answer (score 0):

You just

```
git fetch # in case these branches are from the remote and to be up-to-date

git checkout master

git merge branch_1

git merge branch_2
```

You can now do

```
git status
```

and

```
git log
```

to see the state of master.  It will be local unless/until you explicitly push master to the remote (probably `origin` in your case).

If there are merge commits you'll need to resolve them but you'll get an appropriate message indicating that and that would be a separate question from this.

There are also lots of options with merges and rebasing and relevant topics like fast-forwarding but that is beyond the scope of this question.